# Can astronomers observe neutron stars optically?

Tags: astronomy, neutron-stars

Are there any [neutron stars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_star) near enough for astronomers to observe them optically?  If not, then how close are we to having the technology to do so?

Comment: That edit rather drastically changes the question...

Comment: @ChrisWhite Yes:  thanks for replying !!   I remember that you answered the very-first question which I posted on this site

Comment: I have rolled this back. You had completely changed the question. If you have a new question then ask that separately. Please do not change the nature of the question so that the answers that have been given don't make sense any more.

Comment: SORRY!!   you are absolutely right:  I'll re-post the question  .....

Comment: But also, don't cross-post  http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/16559/

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there are lots of optical observations of isolated (non-pulsar) neutron stars. Such observations have been done for many, many years.

An early example would be [Kulkarni & van Kerwijk (1998)](http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9803024) who detected optical radiation from the counterpart to RX0720.4-3125. The authors discuss various mechanisms that include thermal emission from the surface (if its young) or accretion from the ISM or magnetospheric processes.

Another example is a claimed thermal optical emission detection from the isolated neutron star RXJ185635-3754 by [Walter & Matthews (1997)](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v389/n6649/abs/389358a0.html). A picture of this is shown below, obtained by HST.

Non-thermal emission detected from pulsars is even older news. [Cocke et al. (1969)](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v221/n5180/abs/221525a0.html) detected optical pulsations from the Crab pulsar. Several more pulsars, including millisecond pulsars have been detected at optical wavelengths (e.g. [Shearer & Golden 2002](http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0208579); [Sutaria et al. 2003](http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0301523)).

Knowing the pulse period and phase of a known pulsar facilitates detection by allowing the accumulation of photons at particular times. Old-style photoelectric photometers were well suited to this.

*A visible band HST image of the isolated neutron star RXJ185635-3754, attributable to Walter & Matthews 1997.*
[image: HST image of RXJ185635-3754]

Comment: Were they able to actually image the neutron stars in these observations?

Comment: @PeterR No, there is no telescope that has the angular resolution to image a neutron star, even interferometrically.

Comment: I know that. I was wondering whether they had created star field photos with the neutron star as a small faint spot.

Comment: @PeterR Like this?

Comment: yes, another of the Hubble images. I read that Keck had also produced some images.

Answer (score 4):

There have been a few detected in the visible range by Hubble Space telescope and Keck observatory. The magnitude is less than 25 for the Hubble image(PSR0656+14). Neutron stars are very hot, 600,000 or more Kelvin and very small (Hubble star was 28 kilometers in diameter) so their visible luminosity is very low. The emission is redshifted due to General Relativity effects but remains mostly in  the X-ray range for the black body peak radiation.

Comment: Let's be honest and say that if they're so hot than 1 milion fahrenheit = 1 milion kelvin and use the IS :-P

Comment: Sure, over 555,811 Kelvin then.

Comment: @Peter R  INTERESTING:  I'll try to find more details re that, and would, of course, appreciate if you would send more ...

Comment: Look up Hubble PSR 0656+14. There are a few scientific articles that were written about the Hubble attempt at imaging the neutron star.

Comment: Only *young* neutron stars are very hot, and these are the ones from which thermal optical emission can and has been detected. The peak of the thermal emission is in the soft X-ray or EUV range.

Comment: Most of the result is non-thermal for the Pulsar in the Hubble image. It is mostly from the magnetosphere. Middle age neutron star.

Comment: @PeterR I found a reference to an October-1996 Hubble-photo of a neutron-star, but not the one which you mention'd above ... "fortunately the neutron star lies in front of a molecular cloud known to be about 400 light-years away in the southern constellation Coronae Australis" [  from http://hubblesite.org/newscenter/archive/releases/1997/1997/32/text/ ] ... the quote continues: "The 16.8-mile-diameter [28 km] estimate comes from assuming the neutron star is at the farthest it can be, just in front of the obscuring "wall" of the molecular cloud" ... {[please continue to the next comment]}

Comment: {[continuing]} " ... If instead the neutron star is significantly closer to us, say midway to the molecular cloud, it would be smaller still, and present an even bigger challenge to the theories of the equation of state of nuclear matter" [from hubblesite.org/newscenter/archive/releases/1997/1997/32/text ] ... a careful reading of the quote shows what I'm talking about: they ADMIT that their SIZE-estimate is based on the farthest possible distance which it can be expected to be, and this is obviously to make its calculated SIZE agree with theory .....

Comment: @PeterR I looked up Hubble PSR 0656+14, as you advised, and found this:  "The best candidates for investigation of neutron star (NS) cooling, which depends essentially on still poorly known properties of the superdense matter in NS interiors, are middle-aged ... NSs whose surface temperatures are expected to be in the range of  10^5 to 10^6 K" ... reading further, I found lots of complex maths + charts to explain how they calculate the radius-estimate ... but that's not what I want, and I've edited the question for greater clarity .....

Comment: @RobJeffries Hi Rob:  please note that I have edited my question re the size of neutron-stars, for greater clarity re what I'm asking .....